# Method is not implemented: mobileElement.getAttribute("contentDescription")

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, appium

When try to get attribute of Content description then I get Method is not implemented error in log.

Appium: 1.13
Selenium server: 3.4
junit: 4.13

Tried with mobileElement, webElement.

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("myXpath");
 String tagName = element.getAttribute("contentDescription");

INFO: HTTP Status: '405' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro-user-3.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c5a:4a31:7feb:437b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.turkcell.bip.debug, deviceScreenSize=480x854, networkConnectionEnabled=true, noReset=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=0123456789ABCDEF, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=0123456789ABCDEF, appActivity=com.turkcell.bip.ui.main.BiPActivity, desired={appPackage=com.turkcell.bip.debug, appActivity=com.turkcell.bip.ui.main.BiPActivity, noReset=true, platformVersion=5.1, automationName=Appium, platformName=Android, deviceName=ZTE A465}, platformVersion=5.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, automationName=Appium, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceModel=ZTE Blade A465, platformName=Android, deviceManufacturer=ZTE}]
Session ID: 0d5e93a8-ed21-40c2-893f-9ff5c4bf6682
```

Comment: Try updating selenium to version 3.141